# Why does using share block an observable using withLatestFrom?

Tags: rxjs

**Problem**

I have the following operators:

```
  const prepare = (value$: Observable<string>) =>
    value$.pipe(
      tap((x) => console.log("prepare: ", x)),
      share()
    );

  const performTaskA = (removed$: Observable<string>) =>
    removed$.pipe(tap((x) => console.log("taskA: ", x)));

  const performTaskB = (removed$: Observable<string>) =>
    removed$.pipe(
      tap((x) => console.log("taskB 1: ", x)),
      withLatestFrom(otherValue$),
      tap((x) => console.log("taskB 2: ", x))
    );
```

and I call them like this:

```
  const prepared$ = value$.pipe(prepare);
  const taskADone$ = prepared$.pipe(performTaskA);
  const taskBDone$ = prepared$.pipe(performTaskB);

  merge(taskADone$, taskBDone$).subscribe();
```

resulting in the following output:

```
prepare:  TEST 
taskA:  TEST 
taskB 1:  TEST
```

Note that `taskB 2` has not being logged - it appears the `taskBDone` observable has stalled at the `withLatestFrom(otherValue$)` in `performTaskB`.

If the `share` in `prepare` is removed, the observable does not stall, but it (unsurprisingly) results in `prepare` executing twice, which I do not want.

**Questions**

1. How can I execute both `performTaskA` and `performTaskB` but `prepare` only once?
2. Given the debug explanation below, why does `share` cause the change in emit sequence?

**Demo**
With share (as above): https://codesandbox.io/s/so-share-with-latest-from-with-share-rtyex?file=/src/index.ts:663-853
Without share: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-share-with-latest-from-no-share-p702e

Go to Tests tab on right, ensure the Console is visible and click the Play button.

**Partial Explanation**
Debugging `withLatestFrom` it is evident that when the source(`removed$`) emits, `ready` is `false` [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/190e4d00990e43a10a3c4c9d792dbd089aa267ad/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L101) which prevents emission.

This occurs because when `share` is present, the input(`otherValue$`) subscription emits *after* the source, so `ready` has not yet being set. (Or is it that `share` has caused the source to emit earlier?)

But when `share` is removed, the input  subscription emits *before* the source has, meaning `ready` is set true via [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/190e4d00990e43a10a3c4c9d792dbd089aa267ad/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L83) and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/190e4d00990e43a10a3c4c9d792dbd089aa267ad/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L88), and therefore `withLatestFrom` emits as expected.

Comment: in `performTaskB`, you're using `value$` directly in the `withLatestFrom` - not the shared version returned by `prepare`. But the `removed$` argument is in fact the shared `value$`, so we're using two different versions of `value$` in this function. Is this deliberate?

Comment: It was intentional in that it displayed the problem I was having. However I've edited the question so that now the `withLatestFrom` references a separate variable which is closer to my real world example and still shows the issue.

Comment: Thanks - I think the explanation may be similar-but-not-identical to your other question today. What is the "TEST" observable (as well as `otherValue$`) you're passing in this case?

Comment: I am passing them as cold observables via `TestScheduler`/marbles - see https://codesandbox.io/s/so-share-with-latest-from-with-share-rtyex?file=/src/index.test.ts - which somewhat mimics my real world app where `value$` is a `Subject` and `$otherValue` is hooked up to an ngrx selector. Either way I have the same problem here and in my app. Thanks.

Comment: @backtick I've delved a bit deeper into the problem and updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code and I couldn't get it to hang the way yours does. I suspect it's something about how your testing framework manages observables. I can't replicate it.

I did notice that there are some interleaving/ordering issues inherent with what you've written. Sharing synchronous observables comes with issues such as the first observer synchronously observing all the source values and its completion **before** the second observer can subscribe. This happens even though they should be subscribed "at the same time".

## Ordering with the Event Loop

What I've written here works for me:

```ts
function init(
  value$: Observable<string>,
  otherValue$: Observable<string>
) {
  const prepare = pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("prepare: ", x)),
    delay(0),
    share()
  );

  const performTaskA = pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("taskA: ", x))
  );

  const performTaskB = pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("taskB 1: ", x)),
    withLatestFrom(otherValue$),
    tap(x => console.log("taskB 2: ", x))
  );

  const prepared$ = value$.pipe(prepare);

  merge(
    prepared$.pipe(performTaskA), 
    prepared$.pipe(performTaskB)
  ).subscribe();
}

init(of("a"), of("b"));
```

For me, this prints this to the console:

```html
prepare: a
taskA: a
taskB 1: a
taskB 2: ["a","b"]
```

You'll notice a call to delay(0) within `prepare`. Without that, prepare is called twice since the shared observable has synchronously completed. Delay(0) just puts the next call on the event queue as soon as possible.

That's not the best solution. It's a hack. The best solution depends on how this is used. Most of the time, shareReplay(1) does the job. If you use that here, that will work.

## Ordering with Publish/Connect

Otherwise, you can publish and connect to insure the order is what you'd expect.

Publish/Connect lets you set up all your subscriptions to the source before the source is officially started/connected/subscribed to. This ensures that under the hood, all the callbacks and are in place before anything happens. That's the only way to ensure that a fully synchronous observable can share its values.

```ts
function init(
  value$: Observable<string>,
  otherValue$: Observable<string>
) {
  const prepare = pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("prepare: ", x)),
    share()
  );

  const performTaskA = pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("taskA: ", x))
  );

  const performTaskB = pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("taskB 1: ", x)),
    withLatestFrom(otherValue$),
    tap(x => console.log("taskB 2: ", x))
  );

  const prepared$ = publish()(value$.pipe(prepare));

  merge(
    prepared$.pipe(performTaskA), 
    prepared$.pipe(performTaskB)
  ).subscribe();

  prepared$.connect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and apologies for the delayed response. I appreciate the explanation, however the 1st solution does not represent my scenario (where the input observables do not complete), and the 2nd solution still exhibits the same problem as I originally had - see https://codesandbox.io/s/so-share-with-latest-from-with-share-forked-xihvr?file=/src/index.ts - run the test from the Tests tab on right and observe the console output in the bottom right. In saying that I have since found a different approach  so do not feel obligated to look at this any further!

Comment: I suspect this is something closer to how your testing framework manages Observables rather than an issue with your understanding of RxJS as such. Either way, I'm glad you've figured something out :)